# Regular expression that captures the first letter of the first word and last word

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regular expressions, and I'm trying to figure out how to generate a new column in a dataframe that captures the first initial of a name and the last name.

example `df`:

```
Name           NormName
john smith     j smith
s r peterson   s peterson
sandra oh      s oh
```

This is the code I tried so far, but can't seem to get it to work. I don't know how to get it to just replace the middle part only.

```
namereg = re.compile('(^[a-z])(.*)(\s[a-z]*$)')
names['NormName'] = names.Name.apply(lambda tmp: namereg.sub('',tmp))
```

Comment: Why replace? Just exract it. (Why do you use regex in the first place? Isn't split enough?)

Comment: [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) should be more than enough for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you don't even need to use regex:

```
names['NormName'] = names.Name.apply(lambda tmp: tmp[0]+" "+tmp.rpartition(" ")[2])
```

Comment: There is no need to use regex *unless* there is no need to *validate* the input.

Comment: @zwer Than `rpartition`? Nope.

Answer (score 1):

this should work, please tweak it according to you need.

```
import re
name="john smith"
PATTERN=r'^(\w).*(\s+\w+)$'
MATCH=re.search(PATTERN, name)
print(MATCH.group(1)+MATCH.group(2)
```

Comment: It will work, too, however, note that `\w` also matches digits and `_` char while OP regex clearly matches lowercase ASCII letters only. OP is using pandas, so this approach might turn out a little bit "messier" to implement compared to my suggestion.

Comment: Don't use `ALLCAPS` as variable names. Use `lowercase_with_underscores`

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
names['NormName'] = names['Name'].str.replace(r'^([a-z]).*\s([a-z]+)$', r'\1 \2')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YQWMjD/1).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([a-z])` - Group 1 (referred to with the `\1` placeholer from the replacement pattern): one lowercase ASCII letter
- `.*\s` - any 0+ chars up to the last whitespace
- `([a-z]+)` - Group 2 (referred to with the `\2` placeholer from the replacement pattern): 1+ lowercase ASCII letters at...
- `$` - the end of the string.

Python demo:

```
>>> names['NormName'] =  names['Name'].str.replace(r'^([a-z]).*\s([a-z]+)$', r'\1 \2')
>>> names
           Name    NormName
0    john smith     j smith
1  s r peterson  s peterson
2     sandra oh        s oh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use re.sub. Here ^(\w) first letter, (\b\w+\b$) last word.

```
df['NormName']=df.Name.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'^(\w).*(\b\w+\b$)',r'\1 \2',x))
```